# How I can store the Emacs window/frame configuration along with screen positions

Tags: emacs, window

I have multiple  monitors and I like to spread the emacs buffer  across  monitors using follow-mode.    Often I like to go back to single screen, so that I can utilize the other-applications.   Is it possible to store the size/positional/screen configuration for emacs, so I can restore that after quitting emacs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) you can define a window or frame configuration and record the configuration as a bookmark. Then jump to the bookmark to switch contexts. You can also bookmark a desktop and jump to that.

[Bookmarking a desktop](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#DesktopBookmarks) records more than the current window and frame configuration. You can have any number of desktop bookmarks and switch among them by hitting a key. You can invoke such a bookmark during startup, using a different desktop bookmark for different startup situations (e.g. different platforms, different monitors).